# Making questions more accessible?

Tags: discussion

How can we make our Q/As more accessible to visitors?  What is best practice for making our Q/As easier to read?

Are there things we should avoid because they are unfriendly to our visitors and community members who are using screen readers?

Comment: Is the focus here on 'accessible' as 'easy to understand', or 'accessible' as in 'accessible to people with diabilities'?

Comment: The focus here is on 'accessible to people with disabilites' -- however, I think some of the suggestions which are helpful for people using screen readers, like providing context,  also make the questions easier to read for everyone.

Answer (score 2):

The top places where I think we could improve are:

1. Using descriptive link labels instead of a label like "this page" shows readers where they will go if they click a link.
2. Better use of headings
3. Alt-text and descriptive titles for graphics

People are sharing resources for converting class materials to online learning because of the COVID-19 crisis. As I discover more guidelines, I'll add them to the resource list.

Resources:

[Basic Checklist: Online Content Accessibility](https://webaccess.msu.edu/Help_and_Resources/checklist.html) from Michigan State University